# Edit form load. Error: "There is no row at position 0." [VB.net]

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

Im having a problem on my thesis. It keeps showing the message "There is no row at position 0.". Even though there is a data in my MySql Database. Please help, I'm a newbie. Thanks!

```
Private Sub frmAccountEdit_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        txtUserID.Text = frmAccountList.AccountCaller
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_account WHERE userid = '" & txtUserID.Text & "'", con)
        ds.Reset()
        da.Fill(ds)

        Try
                cmbAccType.SelectedIndex = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(1).ToString
                txtUsername.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(2).ToString
                txtPassword.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(3).ToString
                txtFirst.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(4).ToString
                txtLast.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(5).ToString
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Try trimming the txtUserID.Text, there may be extra spaces which could eventually return false on comparison.

Comment: @pvkcse Can you please tell me how to trim? Thank you

Comment: txtUserID.Text = Trim(txtUserId.Text) also check userid does match with the one at your db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run mysql workbench and try your query in there to get it to work. you will have more informations from your query. if there is no row 0 then your query returns nothing. look for for the row count before trying to access position 0.

I included a class that I used all the time. You also don't want to hard code your query with your textboxes like that. You could get attacked with SQL injection. use some thing like this

```
sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_account WHERE userid=@coluid"
```

then use the addparam function from my class to add your textboxes

```
dim xDB as new mysql
xdb.addparam("@coluid", txtuserid.text)
xdb.execquery(sqlquery)
if xdb.rows.count>0 then 'you have a record

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class mysql

    'Connection string for mysql
    Public SQLSource As String = "Server=1.1.1.1;userid=xuser;password=xpassword;"

    'database connection classes

    Private DBcon As New MySqlConnection
    Private SQLcmd As MySqlCommand
    Public DBDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Public DBDT As New DataTable
    ' parameters
    Public Params As New List(Of MySqlParameter)

    ' some stats
    Public RecordCount As Integer
    Public Exception As String
    Sub ExecQuery(SQLQuery As String)

        DBcon.ConnectionString = SQLSource
        Try
            DBcon.Open()
            SQLcmd = New MySqlCommand(SQLQuery, DBcon)
            'loads params into the query
            Params.ForEach(Sub(p) SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.ParameterName, p.Value))

            'or like this is also good
            'For Each p As MySqlParameter In Params
            ' SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.ParameterName, p.Value)
            ' Next
            ' clears params

            Params.Clear()
            DBDA.SelectCommand = SQLcmd
            DBDA.Update(DBDT)
            DBDA.Fill(DBDT)
            DBcon.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            Exception = ex.Message
        Finally
            DBcon.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
    ' add parameters to the list
    Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
        Dim NewParam As New MySqlParameter(Name, Value)
        Params.Add(NewParam)
    End Sub
End Class
```